# Cannot run video or webcam with OpenCV, Python, and VS Code

Tags: python, macos, opencv, visual-studio-code, webcam

I want to run the following Python code from this [OpenCV tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html) in VS Code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open camera")
    exit()
while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # if frame is read correctly ret is True
    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break
    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv.imshow('frame', gray)
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

I also get the following error from VS Code's terminal:

```
[ WARN:0@0.015] global /private/var/folders/sy/f16zz6x50xz3113nwtb9bvq00000gp/T/abs_506zufg7xt/croots/recipe/opencv-suite_1664548331847/work/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (862) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
```

I believe that my interpreter/virtualenv is correct. My camera's little green light does seem to turn on, if only briefly. The camera works perfectly fine in other situations. But I don't seem to get past the first line of code `cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)` when I run it. Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: What platform and what version of OpenCV is this? This is not an issue with OpenCV per se, but rather the GStreamer backend it's using.

Comment: What if you change this `if not ret:` to `if ret:`? You may have to check VS Code some other path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gstreamer stream is not working with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70753630/gstreamer-stream-is-not-working-with-opencv)

Comment: gstreamer is not actually being used. V4L is being used. if that gstreamer stuff annoys you, simply pass `apiPreference=cv.CAP_V4L` to VideoCapture. then it's not even trying gstreamer. -- @toyotaSupra recommending to break the loop when read() was *successful(!)* is a silly suggestion. vscode has nothing to do with any of this, and neither do paths.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT To be honest, I'm not sure. I don't know what the solution is saying.

Comment: What platform is this?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz OpenCV 4.6, Python 3.9.15, VS Code 1.74.3, MacOS. Anything else you need to know?

Comment: see below, I recommended CAP_AVFOUNDATION instead of V4L. -- is anything complaining about lack of permissions while you run that code? that is/was a common issue on apple, the system denying camera access unless the program asked nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be on Mac OS. Use this:

```
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0, apiPreference=cv.CAP_AVFOUNDATION)
```

Explicit `apiPreference` skips auto-detection of a backend, so the gstreamer backend won't even be attempted.

Comment: I implemented what you suggested, and it fixed the problem. However, the camera turns on and seems to be running, but no window appears with the camera image. I even see a Python script in the lower corner of my apps bar, but there is no window. This doesn't seem to be any issue with the code. Is it VS Code?

Comment: no error messages or system prompts? then I have no idea what could be the issue. don't double-click the code or run it in undefined ways (any "run" button in any IDE). open a terminal and run it from there. then you can be sure that you'll see all the output.

Comment: No error messages or system prompts, as far as I can tell. I did as you suggested and ran the Python code straight from my terminal—it was the same as before: no window with any images, even though everything seemed to run and the camera turned on. If you are as stumped as I am, could you recommend someone who might know what to do?

Comment: I don't know anyone like that. previous questions concerning webcam access on macos involved giving the terminal window itself camera permission, and/or dealing with manifest/plist files. I don't use macos so I can't help with this.

Answer (score 0):

It says that your OpenCV needs Gstreamer as backend to access your camera, but you haven't compiled a Gstreamer-enabled OpenCV.

Comment: no. the gstreamer backend is chatty, even when it's **not being used.** video cameras are usually accessed through the V4L/V4L2 backend. telling OP to (re)compile OpenCV won't change anything at all.

Comment: I tested the code as above. And it worked  for me. And here is my warning using for 4 yrs. >> %Run findface.py
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (961) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Cannot query video position: status=0, value=-1, duration=-1
Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...
[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (509) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to query pipeline state.

Comment: As I said. It nothing wrong  with GSTREAMER and OpenCV. The problem is VS.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I passed the `cap V4L` as you suggested, and it got rid of the path stuff. However, running the code reached `if not cap.isOpened():` and printed "Cannot open camera."

Comment: I was assuming that you're on linux, hence V4L/V4L2. are you on linux or not?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to return here to report on my solution. It turns out that VS Code does not play nicely with conda-based environments. I created a new environment with Python venv; everything now works like a charm.